# Kohana 3.2 Concatenating % to variable when doing a 'where like'

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

### Answer:

I feel like a complete dummy =( I didn't realize it was adding a space at the end of the string in my code. After I rtrim the empty space from the string it all works.

I'm very sorry to have wasted everyones time =S

---

I came across an odd thing, here is an example:

This returns the correct result with no problems.

```
ORM::factory('blog_post')->where('title', 'like', 'this is my 1 post%')->find();
```

This however, doesn't return anything at all...

```
$post_title = 'this is my 1 post';
ORM::factory('blog_post')->where('title', 'like', $post_title.'%')->find();
```

And this doesn't either, **even though the text is the same in all 3 examples**

```
$post_title = 'this is my 1 post%';
ORM::factory('blog_post')->where('title', 'like', $post_title)->find();
```

Any ideas as to why?

Thank you very much for any help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ORM::factory('blog_post')->where('title', 'like', '%'.$post_title.'%')->find();`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried this one as well with no luck =/ Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax has to work.

```
ORM::Factory('foo')->where('bar' , 'like'  , '%'.$foobar.'%')->find();
```

if it is not working, please dump your variable and check the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try ORM::factory('blog_post')->load(null,null)->where('title', 'like', $post_title)->find();

Comment: This didn't work, apparently there is no such method called load in Kohana 3.2 ORM. Inregards to where the % stands, have a look at the examples I have at the top, I'm using the same text except I've placed it inside a variable and merely concatenated a % at the end.